# Integracion del modulo M de materialize Css con Angular 7 & TypeScript

Tags: typescript, modal, materialize, angular7

Hola a toda la comunidad.....

Estoy teniendo un  inconveniente con Typescript y Materialize Css, el tema es que necesito poner la funcionalidad o inicializacion de los elementos de materializeCss en Typescript, pero este no los reconoce mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {TiketService} from '../../services/tiket.service'
import {TiketModel} from '../../models/tiket.model'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lista',
  templateUrl: './lista.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lista.component.css']
})
export class ListaComponent implements OnInit {

  tikets: TiketModel[]=[]; 

  constructor(public listService:TiketService){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.listService.getTikets()
    .subscribe(
      tikets => {
        this.tikets = tikets
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );

   // alert('msg');
    console.log("DATA");
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     //  alert("ingreso funcion");
      var elementoM= document.getElementById("md_add");
      console.log("dato:"+elementoM);
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
      ***var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);***
    });

  }

}
```

Justamente donde esta subrayado es donde no reconoce la instancia y no funciona un modal que necesito abrirlo con estos frameworks de front-end 
del mismo modo con cualquier elemento de materializeCss que deba ser inicializado con JS o Jquery.

Por favor si alguien a podido solucionar este tema su amable ayuda me seria muy util, Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas https://material.angular.io/?

Comment: Es por tema de especificacion de requerimientos del proyecto me indicaron que debo utilizar materializeCss, Gracias por responder si opte por proponer esa opcion pero.....  ¿Al paracer Material tiene menos elementos y facilidad de manejo , es lo que me supieron manisfestar?

Answer (score 0):

¿Probaste con colocar `declare var M: any;`?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {TiketService} from '../../services/tiket.service'
import {TiketModel} from '../../models/tiket.model'

declare var M: any;
```

Comment: Hola Jheyman Mejia gracias por responder te comento provee ponerle "declare var M: any;" como me lo sugeriste en realidad el error se retiro de la consola y me deja compilar el proyecto pero al momento de ejecutar la accion del boton desde el cual estoy llamando, solo llega console.log("dato:"+elementoM); sigue sin interpretar esta linea ***var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);*** ?? tal vez sabes por que ??

Answer (score 0):

instala

```
npm i materialize-css@next --save
```

importa en angular.json

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
            ]
```

en tu modulo (para un materialbox):

```
...
import M from 'materialize-css';
...
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let instances = M.Materialbox.init(document.querySelectorAll('.materialboxed'), {});
      }
```